# Can I use unleaded gas in when premium is required if it's an older model?

Tags: gasoline, lincoln, continental

I have an old 96 Lincoln Continental can I put super unleaded in it if it says it takes premium?

FYI the previous owner put regular unleaded in it for about six months before hand.

Comment: What year is the Continental?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the States: **Premium = Super Unleaded**

There will be different versions of each, as in either can fluctuate, depending on the brand of fuel, between 91 to 93 Octane (R+M/2). You can use Premium or Super Unleaded fuel. Lincoln was probably specifying 91 Octane or better as a premium fuel. This is a typical octane rating specified by vehicle manufacturers when it is required.

The Continental will have knock sensors which would have pulled timing from the engine when the previous owner was using regular unleaded. While this helps prevent engine damage, it also kills engine performance and will affect gas mileage in the process. Your car will most likely run much better on the premium fuel than it has in the past, so be prepared to be pleased.